# Angular routeProvider, how can I not update view, if I'm already on that view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, this is a bit of a silly question, but if I'm on the login page, and I click a link that goes to the login page, I don't want the routeProvider to do anything. Is there a way to do this and is it a good idea to do this?

Some code:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

    //TODO: If already /login, do nothing
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl: '../views/login.ejs',
        controller: 'loginController',
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/register', {
        templateUrl: '../views/register.ejs',
        controller: 'registerController',
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

One potential problem I see is if the user actually wants to manually refresh the page, he wouldn't be able to.

Comment: I think what you described is **the default behavior** in Angular, and it does not prevent the users from reloading the page

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this in your main controller

```
angular.module(..).config(/* your routes */).run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, newUrl, current) {
       // compare previous url to current one - if same, it is navigating to same page
       if (newUrl === current) 
         event.preventDefault(); // This prevents the navigation from happening
    });
});
```

Keep in mind this will work for all routes (I did something generic), and that you're comparing full url (I couldn't find a way to test only routes)

If you want this only for /login then just modify the if clause to

```
if(current.endsWith('/login))
```

and if you need IE suppport (since `endsWith()` is not supported in IE) then use

```
if (current.match("/login$"))
```

Comment: This seems to have blocked all my pages from changing from some reason even if newUrl is different from current...

(I output both urls in console, they're different, yet they still manage to get through that if clause)

Comment: Is there any error on console ? Maybe put the e.preventDefault in curly braces  {}

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
if($location.$$path=='/currentPage')
    //do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: yo shouldn't use $$path, this is implementation dependand, and might change in further versions, breaking the code

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.